# ptxdist autoconf project uses sysroot-host/lib instead of sysroot-target/lib (File format not recognized)

Tags: cross-compiling, autoconf

I have a package in my `ptxdist` project that depends on `libxml2`.

According to this error message it tries to link against libxml2.so in `sysroot-host` which, I think, should be `sysroot-target`:

```
/home/wago/WAGO-PFC/ptxproj-2.4.22/platform-wago-pfcXXX/sysroot-host/lib/libxml2.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can do

```
ptxdist compile libxml2
```

which it does just fine. The file exists and is the correct architecture:

```
platform-wago-pfcXXX/sysroot-target/usr/lib/libxml2.so: ELF 32-bit LSB  shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

All the other dependencies seem to be pulled from the right location. What can I do? Can I set an option in the .rules file?
This is the autoconf specific portion of it:

```
OPENCONNECT_CONF_TOOL   := autoconf
OPENCONNECT_CONF_OPT    := $(CROSS_AUTOCONF_USR)

$(STATEDIR)/openconnect.prepare:
        @$(call targetinfo)
        @$(call clean, $(OPENCONNECT_DIR)/config.cache)
        cd $(OPENCONNECT_DIR) && \
                $(OPENCONNECT_PATH) $(OPENCONNECT_ENV) \
                ./configure $(OPENCONNECT_CONF_OPT) --with-vpnc-script=/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script
        @$(call touch)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure environment variables in the rule file. They are used for the autoconf run. With LDFLAGS you can specify a search path for external libraries:

```
OPENCONNECT_CONF_ENV    := $(CROSS_ENV)\
                           LDFLAGS='-L$(SYSROOT)/lib'

OPENCONNECT_CONF_TOOL   := autoconf
OPENCONNECT_CONF_OPT    := $(CROSS_AUTOCONF_USR
```

But I am not sure if there are any dependencies to the Makefile of your project. 
I could imagine that the additional LDFLAGS parameter will have no effect, if it is not considered in the Makefile of your "OPENCONNECT" project.